# stereoRectifyUncalibrated(hartley rectification) mirrors images

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I've been using Hartley Calibration Algorithm, since stereoCalibrate/stereoRectify delivers no output due to high baseline stereo with camera rotation.

The left image though is heavily sheared and mirrored.

[Stereo images left right. And remapped Images left right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX1za.png)

I've used the anti-shearing algorithm by Zhang, but it doesn't revert the mirroring.

Here is the homography matrix I obtain from stereoRectifyUncalibrated:

```
H1(left):
[-0.09377726121369795, 0.04328690336693735, 86.72993843873914;
 -0.004977161606602101, 0.155454257309974, 3.550060089738537;
 -1.736436872968937e-05, -4.655031712266116e-07, 0.1663350901457538]
```

Here is the shearing transform matrix I obtain from my anti-shearing implementation:

```
shear matrix (left): 
[1.683146574043227, -0.5007180072161737, 0;
 0, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 1]
```

I have to add a translation matrix, because the shearing moves the image to the right, so I calculate:

```
T: 
[1, 0, -144.2016197365122;
 0, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 1]
```

(with T.at(0,2) from:

```
vec = shear * H1 * (0,0)                   //top left point of image
T.at(0,2) = 0 - vec.at(0,0)
```

)

Here is the picture when I calculate the new homography:

```
newH1 = T * shear * H1
```

[Image rectified with anti-sheared homography matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT3ke.png)

Even though the image is now pretty straight and moved into the picture now it is still mirrored....

I have set the first value of H1 to it's positive value, but this is no general solution.
Not all sets(other camera sets) do get mirrored, but as far as I could see, findChessboard finds the boards correctly (also correct in order).

[OpenCV findFundamentalMat very unstable and sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251676/opencv-findfundamentalmat-very-unstable-and-sensitive)
I've read that findFundamental is 'unstable' sometimes do I have to calculate the fundamental matrix myself?

Thanks in advance!